# How to sort the arraylist from hashmap?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, sorting

Im using hashmap and arraylist...
How to sort the arraylist ?   eg) In hashmap values are in order like one,two,three,four,five
but i stored these values in arraylist the order changed like three,one,five,two,four

In my code groupList,gnamelist and newList  are all arraylist...
In print sts PLACES are in correct order but while print on NEWLIST PLACES the order changed
How to sort this in order?

My code

> ```
>     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
>       // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
>       map.put(TAG_PLACE, gname);
>       map.put(TAG_HOTEL,lname);
>      // adding HashList to ArrayList
>       groupList.add(map);
>       gnamelist.add(gname);
>       System.out.println("PLACES" + gnamelist);
>       List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(gnamelist));
>       Collections.sort(newList,Collections.reverseOrder());
>       System.out.println("NEWLIST PLACES" + newList);
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HashSet will store elements in an unordered fashion, and is likely the culprit of your element reordering.

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(new HashSet<String>(gnamelist));
```

Also consider using LinkedHashMap/LinkedHashSet, which preserves the ordering of elements added to it.

Alternatively try the following:

```
gnamelist.add(gname);
System.out.println("PLACES" + gnamelist);
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
newList.addAll(gnamelist);
```

Comment: Why are you using the HashSet at all?  You can just use AddAll to add all elements from one list to another. (See my revised answer above)

Comment: ok then how to sort the 'grouplist' array in that i have add map values, two values..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Collections.sort(newList);
```

**Edit:**

If you want to sort in reverse use this

```
Collections.sort(newList,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

**Important:**

if you want to preserve insertion order, you need to use `TreeSet` instead of HashSet as HashSet doesn't preserve insertion order

Comment: no i didn't get it in order, now it changed some other order like four,three,two,five,one

Comment: Now also its not in order, now its in some other order..How to use TreeSet

Comment: @OneManArmy If it doesn't worked then use `LinkedHashSet` that should for sure

Comment: List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(gnamelist));
     Collections.sort(newList,Collections.reverseOrder());
     System.out.println("NEWLIST GRADES" + newList);     Now also not in ordered...

Comment: @OneManArmy don't sor t when you use `LinkedHashSet`